# How to let DataGridView ignore certain properties when bind to an IList object

Tags: winforms

As title. I wondering if there is some attributes to control?

Comment: Can you post an example of _exactly_ what you are trying to do? It is not clear from your question. What properties? Ignore in what way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, no attribute. You can delete columns after binding or set AutoGenColumns=false and only add specific columns.

Answer (score 16):

```
[System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
```

Comment: this answer should be marked as the solution!